# Laravel: Ajax POST request execute the POST one and a second GET one not wanted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Given this function to execute the POST request:

```
$.post('../CPaddVolo/',{
                  _token: $('#_token').val(),
                  data:values
                }).done(function(){
                  if (msg==='ok'){
                    swal("Volo aggiunto con successo!");


                  }else{
                    swal("Errore nella gestione della richiesta: riprovare.");
                  }
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                    swal("Aggiunta del volo fallita.");
                });
```

Whole HTML code and JS in the page:

#### Modulo voli

```
                      <div class="row">
                        <!--Voli presenti-->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label>Voli presenti</label>
                          @if (count($data[6])>0)
                            @foreach ($data[6] as $volo)
                            <form action="{{route('updateVolo',$data[6]->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                              <label for="compagnia">
                                Compagnia di volo
                              </label>
                              <select class="form-control" id="newVoloidCompagniaFk" name="compagnia">
                                  @foreach ($data[11] as $compagnia)
                                    @if ($compagnia->id===$volo->idCompagniaFk)
                                      <option value="{{$compagnia->id}}" selected="selected">
                                        {{$compagnia->nome}}
                                      </option>
                                    @else
                                    <option value="{{$compagnia->id}}">
                                      {{$compagnia->nome}}
                                    </option>

                                    @endif
                                  @endforeach
                              </select>

                              <label for="dataoraPart">Data e ora di partenza (gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm)</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}dataoraPart" name="dataoraPart"/>

                              <label for="dataoraArrivo">Data e ora di arrivo (gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm)</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}dataoraArrivo" name="dataoraArrivo"/>

                              <label for="origine">Origine:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}origine" name="origine" />

                              <label for="destinazione">Destinazione:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}destinazione" name="destinazione" />

                              <label for="classe">Classe:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}classe" name="classe" />

                              <label for="servizi">Servizi:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}servizi" name="servizi" />

                              <label for="buy">Buy:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}buy" name="buy" />
                              <label for="sell">Sell:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}sell" name="sell" />
                              <label for="bar">BAR:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}bar" name="bar" />

                              <label for="istruzioni">Istruzioni:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="volo{{$volo->id}}istruzioni" name="istruzioni" />

                              <label for="status">Stato:</label>
                              <select name="status" id="volo{{$volo->id}}status">
                                @foreach($data[12] as $status)
                                  @if ($status->id===$volo->status)
                                    <option value="{{$status->id}}" selected="selected">
                                        {{$status->nome}}
                                    </option>
                                  @else
                                    <option value="{{$status->id}}" >
                                        {{$status->nome}}
                                    </option>
                                  @endif
                                @endforeach
                              </select>

                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Modifica volo"/>
                            </form>
                            @endforeach
                          @else
                            <br/>

                          Nessun volo presente per la proposta cliente.
                          @endif
                        </div>
                        <!--Aggiunta di un nuovo volo-->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label>Aggiunta nuovo volo</label><Br/>


                          <label for="compagnia">
                            Compagnia di volo
                          </label>
                          <select class="form-control" id="newVoloidCompagniaFk" name="compagnia">
                            <option value="0">
                              Seleziona una compagnia di volo
                            </option>
                              @foreach ($data[11] as $compagnia)

                                <option value="{{$compagnia->id}}">
                                  {{$compagnia->nome}}
                                </option>


                              @endforeach
                          </select>

                          <label for="dataoraPart">Data e ora di partenza (gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm)</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolodataoraPart" name="dataoraPart"/>

                          <label for="dataoraArrivo">Data e ora di arrivo (gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm)</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolodataoraArrivo" name="dataoraArrivo"/>

                          <label for="origine">Origine:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVoloorigine" name="origine" />

                          <label for="destinazione">Destinazione:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolodestinazione" name="destinazione" />

                          <label for="classe">Classe:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVoloclasse" name="classe" />

                          <label for="servizi">Servizi:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVoloservizi" name="servizi" />

                          <label for="buy">Buy:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolobuy" name="buy" />
                          <label for="sell">Sell:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolosell" name="sell" />
                          <label for="bar">BAR:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVolobar" name="bar" />

                          <label for="istruzioni">Istruzioni:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newVoloistruzioni" name="istruzioni" />

                          <label for="status">Stato:</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="status" id="newVolostatus">
                            <option value="0">
                              Seleziona uno stato
                            </option>
                            @foreach($data[12] as $status)

                                <option value="{{$status->id}}" >
                                    {{$status->nome}}
                                </option>

                            @endforeach
                          </select>
                          <br/>
                          <br/>
                          <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addVolo()">Aggiungi nuovo volo</button>




                        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testo').summernote();

  });


function proposalDelete(id){
  swal("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa proposta cliente?",{
    buttons:{
      cancel: "Annulla",
      conferma: "Conferma"

    }
  })
  .then((value)=>{
    switch(value){
      case "cancel":
        swal("Operazione annullata");
        break;
      case "conferma":{

        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '../CPDelete/'+id

         }).done(function( msg ) {
             if (msg==='ok'){
               swal("Proposta cliente eliminata.");

               window.location='../clientProposals';
             }else{
               swal("Errore nella gestione della richiesta: riprovare.");
             }

         });
      };break;
    }
  });

}


(function() {
    document.getElementById('datainizio').value=document.getElementById('datainizio').value.substr(8,2)+'/'+document.getElementById('datainizio').value.substr(5,2)+'/'+document.getElementById('datainizio').value.substr(0,4);
    document.getElementById('datafine').value=document.getElementById('datafine').value.substr(8,2)+'/'+document.getElementById('datafine').value.substr(5,2)+'/'+document.getElementById('datafine').value.substr(0,4);

})();


function addVolo(){
  swal("Procedere all'aggiunta del nuovo volo?",{
    buttons:{
      cancel: "Annulla",
      conferma: "Conferma"

    }
  })
  .then((value)=>{
    switch(value){
      case "cancel":
        swal("Operazione annullata");
        break;
      case "conferma":{

        if ((isValidDatetime($('#newVolodataoraPart').val())) && (isValidDatetime($('#newVolodataoraArrivo').val()))){
          if (($('#newVoloidCompagniaFk').val()!=0) && ($('#newVolostatus').val()!=0)){
            values=[];
            $('*[id*=newVolo]:visible').each(function() {

                  if ( ($(this).attr('id')!='newVoloidCompagniaFk') || ($(this).attr('id')!='newVolostatus')){
                    if ( ($(this).attr('id')=='newVolobar') ||
                          ($(this).attr('id')=='newVolobuy') ||
                            ($(this).attr('id')=='newVolosell')
                        ){
                      if (!isNaN($(this).val())){
                        values.push($(this).val());
                      }

                    }
                    else if ( ($(this).attr('id')=='newVolodataoraPart') || ($(this).attr('id')=='newVolodataoraArrivo')){

                        values.push(datetimeComposer($(this).val()));

                    }
                    else{
                      if ($(this).val().length>0){
                        values.push($(this).val());
                      }
                    }

                  }

              });

              values.push($('#CPID').val());
              if (values.length!=13){
                swal("Accertati di aver riempito tutti i campi e che gli indici di BAR, buy e sell siano numerici.");
              }else{
                console.log("eseguo");
                $.post('../CPaddVolo/',{
                  _token: $('#_token').val(),
                  data:values
                }).done(function(){
                  if (msg==='ok'){
                    swal("Volo aggiunto con successo!");


                  }else{
                    swal("Errore nella gestione della richiesta: riprovare.");
                  }
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                    swal("Aggiunta del volo fallita.");
                });


              }





          }else{
            swal("Selezionare una compagnia di volo e uno stato del volo stesso.");
          }

        }else{
          swal("Gli orari di partenza e arrivo non hanno un formato corretto.");
        }


      };break;
    }
  });

}

function datetimeComposer(value){
  return value.substr(6,4)+'-'+value.substr(3,2)+'-'+value.substr(0,2)+' '+value.substr(11,5)+':00';
}
//Verifica che la data orario sia scritta in formato corretto
function isValidDatetime(value){
  data=value.substr(0,10);
  ora=value.substr(11,5);

  if (value.length==16){
    if (value.substr(0,10) != '' && value.substr(0,10).match(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/)){
      if (value.substr(11,5)!='' && value.substr(11,5).match(/^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/)){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;




}
```

And this routing into my "web.php":

```
Route::post('/cms/CPaddVolo/', 'DetailsClientProposalController@addVolo')->name('addVolo');
```

Will be executed the first POST request (with any response given):

[image: first POST request result]

Then, simultaneously, will be executed a second GET request that isn't done in any part of my code:

[image: GET request not wanted]

And this, will throws an error (because the routing doesn't allow a GET request):

```
GET http://amaka.demomasetek.online/cms/CPaddVolo 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Actually, I tried also to set in the POST the entire URL with same result, but this problem still persists, I thought meanwhile that the problem was the last "/" in the URL itself: same result with or without.

Same result using `$.ajax` and the the "POST" set as parameters inside the callback.

Comment: Are you sure you don't execute this request twice in your javascript?

Comment: @Danoctum yes. I checked another time and it'll be exectued only one time...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the html/jquery?

Comment: @Danoctum just done.

Comment: The function "addVolo()" will perform different checks on fields related to the "values" array filled.
If everything will be ok, will be executed the post.

The "swal" library is used just to create prettier alert dialog windows.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from my understanding you are trying to excute 2 route consecutively? First one is a POST request, while the second one is a GET request?

```
//this is your first request using POST  
$.post('../CPaddVolo/',{
                  _token: $('#_token').val(),
                  data:values
                }).done(function(){
                  if (msg==='ok'){
                    secondCPaddVolo(); //call it in success function
                    swal("Volo aggiunto con successo!");



                  }else{
                    swal("Errore nella gestione della richiesta: riprovare.");
                  }
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                    swal("Aggiunta del volo fallita.");
                });


function secondCPaddVolo(){
  $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  data: {yourdata},
  url: '../CPaddVolo/', //whatever your URL is
  successs: function(data){
    //return your data
  },
  error: function(data){
  //return
 }
});


}
```

What you can do is call your second request in the success function of your first AJAX. I hope this is what you meant. If you want another approach, you can call the controller function of your second request inside the controller function of your first request.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding: the second GET request ISN'T wanted, instead: will be performed...

Comment: https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-return-empty-response-690f8a308d9a?source=linkShare-1aa3d5cca22b-1531233036

Comment: Don't mind, probably I've written in a not so wonderful way, by the way it doesn't seem to be a problem related to configuration... Many thanks anyway :)